# Excel VBA Can't access sheet on external workbook

Tags: vba, function, excel

I have created a custom function in Excel using VBA. I'm trying to get data from a different workbook using the `Workbooks.Open(path)` command. Here's my code:

```
Option Explicit

Function TestFunction() As String
  mySub
  TestFunction = "Success."
End Function


Sub mySub()

  Dim path As String
  Dim wk As Workbook

  path = "C:\Users\jg\Desktop\machine_data.xlsm"
  Set wk = Workbooks.Open(path)

  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Set ws = wk.Sheets(1)
  Debug.Print ws.Range("A2")
End Sub


Sub Test()
  Debug.Print (TestFunction())
End Sub
```

Now my problem is the following:

When I run the `Sub Test()` within the VBA environment from Excel everything works as planned. `machine_data.xlsm` gets opened and the field `A2` shows up in debug.

Once I go to the workbook where I defined this module in and type `=TestFunction()` into a cell, I get a `#VALUE!`. The file also doesn't get opened.

If I comment these two lines:

```
  Set ws = wk.Sheets(1)
  Debug.Print ws.Range("A2")
```

the cell will show `Success!`, but the file still doesn't open.

What am I doing wrong? Both workbooks are `.xlsm` files. I am using Microsoft Office Excel 2007.

Comment: A UDF can only return a value - have a look at [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045826/excel-vba-function-to-turn-activecell-to-bold).

Comment: @DaveU I have read about this yes, but Isn't opening a external workbook and only reading from it and depending on read values returning a different value allowed? Because it seems like that's not even possible. I'm not changing any values in the `machine_data.xlsm` file.

Comment: @DaveU Nevermind I chose a different workaround (see my own answer below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As DaveU already stated UDFs can only return values. I found a different workaround simply calling the function from within the VBA environment which lets me modify cell contents wherever I'd like.

Answer (score 0):

Just throw everything from mySub into the test function and if everything is successful have test function return the value of the cell. So testFunc = ws.Range("A2").

Comment: Still get the `#VALUE!` when copying `mySub` into `TestFunction()`.